# Can 3 phase AC current be applied to a BLDC and vise versa?

Tags: motor, ac, brushless-dc-motor

I am just wondering because the designs of a synchronous motor and BLDC are the same. Could you please explain the downsides of not using the designated current?

Comment: You can't just apply line voltage to a BLDC. It won't start. But if you somehow spin it up to line speed, then switchover, you can do that. I am sure it will work fine as long as the voltage and frequency are appropriate.

Comment: People drive BLDC's with sinusoidal current quite frequently.

Comment: Yes and no? A BLDC and 3 Phase AC motor are very similar obviously and some will work in both configurations (either because they were designed to, or they do by accident). But you couldn't count on it working with every motor every time.

Comment: To Marko Buršič:
BLDC motors can also be controlled using three-phase sine waves.
It can even be said that only sine wave control can achieve the highest efficiency. [The Difference Between Motors Commutation BLDC vs (FOC Trapeziodal / Sinosuidal)](https://electric-skateboard.builders/t/the-difference-between-motors-commutation-bldc-vs-foc-trapeziodal-sinosuidal/3002)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not the same.

In BLDC machine, the stator winding is concentrated. Hence the stator waveform will be trapezoidal. Whereas in PMSM the stator winding is distributed winding. Hence the stator waveform is sinusoidal.

[image]

For PMSM a suitable control is space vector modulation, whereas for BLDC the six step pulse switchig is more apropiate.

The downside of using different control method is cogging output torque of the motor.

Comment: I have looked at the back emf from several BLDC motors. Never is it as trapezoidal as shown. It is much more rounded. More or less sinusoidal. A BLDC with sine drive will often be more efficient and quieter than when driven with 6-step.

Comment: Yeah, my understanding is that you can optimize the BEMF of a BLDC to be more trapezoidal like which makes it run more efficiently with a trapezoidal drive waveform (which is, obviously, much easier to produce than a sinusoidal one), but that doesn't mean it has to adhere to strictly be driven by one to run.

Answer (score 0):

Marko bursic, you are right, but I have to add that in a flux ,3Φ signoidal and separated by 120°, your magnets will end up their magnetic life very fast. This is the reason why there are no permenant magnets in 3phase induction motors.